# Configuring Angular2 project with myeclipse

Tags: angular, angular-cli, myeclipse

I am using myeclipse 2017 that supports Angular2. I have created an Angular project that internally use `angular-cli` to create projects. While creating projects following commands are executed by default

```
npm install @angular/cli
npm install angular-ide --save-dev
ng new project_name
```

Every time I create a project it installs `angular-cli`.

How can I use system installed angular-cli?

And I want to run last command `ng new project_name` with --minimal flag, how can I do that?

Is there any way to configure these commands?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you can't specify a system installed angular-cli, it is installed in the project as a dependency. You can, however, specify the system installed node and npm versions (selectable in the drop down box for those items). Sadly, there is also no way to configure the "ng new" command, either. If you use the Genuitec forums to request an enhancement, it will be considered for inclusion in a future release. However, you can always create the project outside of MyEclipse using your own ng command and then import it as an Angular project - not the ideal solution but workable.

Comment: Is there any way to link two angular projects in myeclipse like we specify for java projetcs?

Comment: Well, you can do it in a similar way. Right click on the project and select Properties then go to the Javascript/Include Path page and click the Projects tab. Add another project from there.

Comment: I have a project having a module that contains multiple components (created index.ts file for this and exported components). now how can I use this module in other angular project? I